# Sneak attack advancement feat

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e, druid, rogue, sneak-attack

One of my players is trying to play as a rogue/druid (mostly for sneak attacking). Unfortunately, these classes don't have a lot of synergy. Are there any feats or items, ideally for pathfinder, that allow a character to increase sneak attack dice while taking levels in a class like druid? I'm hoping for something similar to Monastic Legacy (a feat which lets you advance unarmed damage dice like a monk while leveling another class), but for the sneak attack mechanic.

Answer (score 7):

*Complete Adventurer* had a prestige class for 3.5 called the daggerspell shaper, which advanced Sneak Attack, Spells, and Wild Shape.

As for feats, I am not aware of any, but in the same vein as Daring Outlaw etc. from *Complete Scoundrel*, this feat seems quite reasonable:

> ## Natural Ambusher
>
> #### Requirements:
>
> - Sneak Attack +2d6
> - Trackless Step
>
> #### Benefit:
>
> Your druid levels stack with your rogue levels for the purposes of how much bonus damage you add on a Sneak Attack. For instance, a druid 4/rogue 3 with this feat would deal 4d6 extra damage on a Sneak Attack, as a rogue 7 would.
>
> Your rogue levels stack with your druid levels for the purposes of Nature Bond as well as your daily uses and options for Wild Shape. For example, a druid 4/rogue 3 with this feat could have an Animal Companion with the Devotion feature, and could use Wild Shape twice per day, since the druid’s effective level would be 7 and these features are available at druid 6.

Comment: I don't know if I would consider a bonus to reflex and ac to be equivalent to what are arguably the two most powerful features from the most powerful base class. I think for that feat to be remotely balanced, it should advance one or the other of animal companion/wild shape

Comment: @Scott, I'd say that feat is OK. Anyone trying to use it is paying for SA dice with Druid caster levels. A bad trade.

Comment: @Scott Not the two most powerful features, nor the most powerful class. The second and third most powerful features (it does not progress spellcasting, which is definitely the most powerful feature), of the, eh, probably fourth-most-powerful class (after arcanist, cleric, and wizard).

Comment: @ KRyan Cleric is only better if the DM permits nightstick cheese. Wizard is less good, but with better prestige classes. Arcanist is not a base class. You're right about it being 2nd and 3rd best ability.

Comment: @ ernir - Anyone druid using it makes that tradeoff. Any rogue using it loses almost nothing to gain an incredible amount of power and utility.

Comment: @ Actually, I've changed my mind about it being overpowered. It probably wouldn't make you more powerful than a straight druid, and for a rogue that one feat probably takes you from tier 4 to the top of tier 3. If the rest of the party is playing tier 1-3, then this feat is balanced. If everyone is playing 4-5, then I suspect it will destroy balance.

Comment: @Scott Sure, but in such a game a straight druid would be *worse*.

Comment: @Scott missed this before. We are talking primarily Pathfinder here. Not that your assessment is accurate in 3.5, IMO, but Pathfinder did nerf the droid a fair bit, so now it's almost certainly the "weakest" of tier 1s. Oh and arcanist is a new base class in PF, and it is insane. Spontaneous casting but you can change your spells known every day, off the Sor/Wiz list, and free metamagic to boot.

Comment: @Scott, if you think the animal companion is the most powerful part of the druid, you haven't looked at level 3+ druid buff spells.  They are pretty damn bonkers.  A Druid 7 is going to be much much more powerful than a Druid 4/Rogue 3 with this feat, even in pathfinder.

Comment: @ kRyan - yes, I was responding based on the 3.5 tag in the question.

@ Jack - Read my earlier comment. It is not more powerful than straight druid, but is a hell of a lot better than straight rogue.

Comment: @Scott I took the "ideally Pathfinder" request in the question as implying that Pathfinder was primary, so when both games have something, they were using the Pathfinder version. Regardless, if Pathfinder material is available, the arcanist *is* a base class; 3.5 doesn’t have a class by that name to my knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

There is also the [Accomplished Sneak Attacker](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/accomplished-sneak-attacker) feat that gives you an extra 1D6 to your sneak attack.

It has the limitation that it can't boost the total number of dice beyond half your character level (round up) so is only useful to multi-class characters.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes timing is everything. Paizo has just launched their [Advanced Class Guide](http://paizo.com/products/btpy978v?Pathfinder-Roleplaying-Game-Advanced-Class-Guide). The book is filled with Hybrid classes that mix features from different parent classes.

The book does not contain a Druid / Rogue hybrid. However, it does contain about 10 pages of material for a building a reasonable Hybrid class. It also has *even more* archetypes. So you may find that building your own is satisfying.

Likewise there are dozens of [Druid Archetypes](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid). If your player primarily wants Sneak Attack + Shape Change, then maybe you just keep them as a druid and cobble together an archetype that grants them a slower growing Sneak Attack.

Comment: Actually the ACG does have a druid archetype with sneak attack, though only a single die. However my player has low system mastery and seems to be a bit wary of the archetypes in general. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any hybrid Druid/Rogue classes. However a feat that would help is **Savage Grapple** from *Complete Adventurer* which allows you to sneak attack while grappling in wild shape. **Telling blow** is a feat that'd allow you to sneak attack when you critical strike (I'd presume it'd work in wild shape, confirm with DM).

Comment: I found that out a bit after my comment when trying to find it.